# Formatting of the file for exporting images is not correct with the prettier

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I am using vscode and have prettier working nicely and correlated with my colleagues in general. However, after saving index.js file (example scene shown below) for exporting images, its formatting causes problem in merge requests and hard to track changes. How to make it right? Thanks in advance.

[Exports: desired vs undesired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqe2r.png)

I tried uninstalling and installing vscode delete node-modules and package-lock.json and run npm install and even disabling all extensions, but problem still continues and only unpractical hack thorugh the solution that i can find is save file without formatting and put my export somewhere inde the file hoping its in the right position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prettier ignore to achieve that, just wrap your imports around **prettier-ignore-start** and **prettier-ignore-end**. An example would be:

```
// prettier-ignore-start
import {mycomponet} from "./components"
// prettier-ignore-end
```

Comment: I could not make it work unfortunately by the way, and use save without formatting (Ctrl +  K + Ctrl + Shift + S).